# calculate memory requirements of uninformed search algorithms

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence

Following state space consist of a computer requiring 2KB for storing a node. I have to compute memory requirements for breadth first, depth first and iterative deepening search algorithms. How do I calculate it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much experience in AI but sharing some link hope it would help you what you need.
http://intelligence.worldofcomputing.net/ai-search/breadth-first-search.html#.Vq3p1lKzkqc
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search

Comment: Thanks @Akash, in some answers, they calculate memory requirements only based on the resulting queue generated, but in some, they have considered both open and close lists. I couldn't find any standard way of calculating it.

Comment: @Kanishka i am new to AI need some help regarding same

Comment: Same here, we did AI during previous semester. Although I don't have a lot experience, glad to help.